# ctypes error in python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-3.3

In Python(command line)

I run  `import ctypes`  it is ok

But if I run `c:\python33\python.exe  test.py`

this file only one line  `import ctypes`

I get the following error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not a valid Win32 application`

I only installed python3.3 64 bit

Please help!

Comment: What are you running to get your command line where `import serial` works? Is it `c:\python33\python.exe`, or some other interpreter?

Comment: Did you install for 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: It is c:\python33\python.exe.  And two all 64 bit.

Comment: Try loading the extension module explicitly. Change your script as follows: `import imp; imp.load_dynamic('_ctypes', r'C:\Python33\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd')`.